# SPE prevent Get-Item from throwing error if no item found

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm writing a script to show the missing/new items between two content branches. For the target of the comparison, I build an item path and then call `Get-Item` on that path to see if there is an equivalent item. The problem is that Get-Item throws an exception if no item is found - I would just like to handle a case of a 'null' item in my script.

```
#$source is the root path of the source branch
$localPath = $sourceItem.Paths.FullPath.SubString($source.Length)
$targetPath = "master:" + $target + "/" + $localPath
$targetItem = Get-Item $targetPath
```

The script works in that $targetItem is null if no item is found using $targetPath but I would like to suppress the error message in the script.

Comment: Have you considered using `Compare-Object`? This may be more efficient for you. Essentially use `Get-ChildItem` for both trees and compare two properties (item path such as _/sitecore/content/home_).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the standard PowerShell error handling parameters:

```
$localPath = $sourceItem.Paths.FullPath.SubString($source.Length)
$targetPath = "master:" + $target + "/" + $localPath
$targetItem = Get-Item $targetPath -ErrorAction Ignore
```

Sounds like in your case this would be more than enough. But if you want the ability to check for other potential errors, you could combine the `SilentlyContinue` action with the `ErrorVariable` option, and then act out based on what's in the variable. For instance:

```
# ...
$targetItem = Get-Item $targetPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable myError
if ($myError.Count -gt 0 -and
    !($myError[0].FullyQualifiedErrorId.Contains("ItemDoesNotExist"))) {
    Write-Warning $myError[0]
}
```

Lots more details in this blog post: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/09/handling-errors-the-powershell-way/